# How to use re-CAPTCHA with shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to use [shinyCAPTCHA](https://github.com/carlganz/shinyCAPTCHA) package with shinydashboard, but it is not working correctly. What is the correct way to use it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyCAPTCHA)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"),
                uiOutput(outputId = "captcha"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  result <- callModule(recaptcha, "test", secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe")
  output$captcha <- renderUI({
    req(result()$success)
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
      set.seed(122);histdata <- rnorm(500)
      hist(histdata[seq_len(input$slider)], main = "Histrogram", xlab = "x") })
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(title = "Controls",sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is probably more related to getting info out of a module than shinycaptcha

Comment: The issue is that  you can't access the data in slider, I haven't used too many modules so I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

This is less bad I think

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyCAPTCHA)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"),
                uiOutput(outputId = "captcha"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  result <- callModule(recaptcha, "test", secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe")
  output$captcha <- renderUI({
    req(result()$success)
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
      set.seed(122);histdata <- rnorm(500)
      req(reactive(input$slider)())
      hist(histdata[seq_len(reactive(input$slider)())], main = "Histrogram", xlab = "x") })
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(title = "Controls",sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```